# Free Tab Navigation Plugin for Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: plugins, microsoft-office-2010

how to add a tab navigation to office 2010 (to open multiple documents in the same window)? is there a free plugin for this feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is and it is located here: [WordAddinTabs](http://office-addin.com/download.html)